# Does DynamoDB have any feature which will check if the value is not duplicated for a non-key attribute?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does DynamoDB have any feature which will check if the value is not duplicated for a non-key attribute?
first request body
{
"product ID":"ab123";
"parameter":"test"
}
second Request Body
{
"productID":"ab12",
"parameter":"test"
}
At the time of second request , the dynamodb should throw error as both productID have same parameter value

Is there any feature ?

Comment: No. DynamoDB is a key value store and there are features to find values quickly by indexing the key attributes, i.e. the GSI. Looping through the values to find duplicates is very expensive, because you need to scan all items. I would suggest, that you use partition key to avoid duplicates. See https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann This is is correct, post it as an answer and you'll get a +1.